# org.mule.api.MessagingException: Must declare the table variable "@P0"

Tags: database, jdbc, mule

I have the following error when I try to UPDATE a Table via JDBC - SQL Server Configuration in Database Connector:

```
org.mule.api.MessagingException: Must declare the table variable "@P0". (com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException).
```

My code fragment is this:

```
<db:update config-ref="SQLSERVER_C" doc:name="UPDATE TABLE">
    <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[UPDATE #[flowVars.c_table]
SET C_STATUS= #[flowVars.errorNo], PROCESSED=GETDATE(), RETRY=#[flowVars.retry], MESSAGE=#[flowVars.error]
WHERE 
ACCOUNT = #[flowVars.accountNo]
AND LTRIM(RTRIM(SRVORDNO)) = #[flowVars.servOrdNo]]]></db:parameterized-query>
</db:update>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK. I did realize what happened here...

As you can see, I'm using a parametrized query. My bad.

I have no problem with parametrized queries where I use a explicit table name. (Just text, not a flowVar value nor a MEL expression).

But, according to documentation https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/database-connector#query-types It eems that I cannot use a variable table name, or a variable portion of the SQL Statement in general... Just the "parameter values".

In the other hand, I was able to use dynamic query for this purpose, but I had to ensure the correctness of data inserted (quoted strings in this simple case).

The working code shows as follows:

```
<db:update config-ref="SQLSERVER_C" doc:name="UPDATE TABLE">
    <db:dynamic-query><![CDATA[UPDATE #[flowVars.c_table]
SET C_STATUS= #[flowVars.errorNo], PROCESSED=GETDATE(), RETRY=#[flowVars.retry], MESSAGE='#[flowVars.error]'
WHERE ACCOUNT='#[flowVars.accountNo]' AND LTRIM(RTRIM(SRVORDNO))='#[flowVars.serviceOrderNo]']]></db:dynamic-query>
</db:update>
```